# What sort of sorting problems did the first computers tackle?

Tags: sorting

I'd like to trace the narrative of sorting, since it is such a fundamental algorithm taught in classes. Was insertion sort always seen as naive in a way? How did the punch computers first start sorting things?

Thanks in advance, and it really does enrich my learning of algorithms.

Comment: Read vol 3 of Knuth: Sorting and Searching. Pay attention to mergesort and Tape sorting.

Comment: Card sorters use radix sort, least significant digit first. Tape sorts were [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Use_with_tape_drives) , or a variation called [polyphase merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphase_merge_sort).

Answer (score 1):

[IBM](https://www.ibm.com) used to dominate the market on sorting machines. See the [IBM Card Sorters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_card_sorter) page on Wikipedia. That page describes how their machines sorted the cards, using their punch card system.

The page also has a photo of the [Hollerith tabulating machine with sorting box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabulating_machine).
That tabulating machine, was designed to compile the **US Census data** in 1890. The first major problem which the US Census faced in 1880 was *time*. The second & third were *resources*, as in *people* & *money*.

From the Hollerith Wikipedia link:

> The 1880 census had taken eight years to process. Since the U.S.
>   Constitution mandates a census every ten years to apportion both
>   congressional representatives and direct taxes among the states, a
>   larger staff or faster method was required.

[ENAIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC) was created 56 years later and became operational in 1946.

> Although ENIAC was designed and primarily used to calculate artillery
>   firing tables for the United States Army's Ballistic Research
>   Laboratory, its first programs included a study of the feasibility of
>   the thermonuclear weapon.

This was also the first computerized sort algorithm, although the Wikipedia page doesn't specify which type of sort that was implemented.

> Betty Holberton (née Snyder) continued on to invent the first sorting
>   algorithm and help design the first commercial electronic computers,
>   the UNIVAC and the BINAC, alongside Jean Jennings.

If you want to dig more into sorting algorithms, check out the [Sorting Algorithms Animations](https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms) on [Toptal](https://www.toptal.com) on sorting lists of data. Then dig into this [Sorting Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) Wikipedia page for more details on each type of sort.

Comment: It should be noted that card sorters use radix sort, least significant digit first.